# How can I write reusable classes to make http async requests?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a project where I want to write some functions that use internet service to get the data from the `MySQL` server. These functions are inside some non-activity classes. I intend to call these functions from different activities. I use `AsyncTask` to make **HTTP** requests. Following is the skeleton of my design.

```
public class MyLibrary{
    String myData;

    protected String getMyData(String param){
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("param1", apicall);
        params.put("param2", param);
        MyAsyncClass myAsyncClass = new MyAsyncClass(params);
        myAsyncClass.execute();

        /* Here after finishing the task I want to return the data to the caller */
        return myData;
    }

    private class MyAsyncClass extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        MyAsyncClass(HashMap<String, String> params) {
            this.postData = params;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();
            return requestHandler.sendPostRequest(GlobalConstants.myurl, postData);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            /* parse code here ... */
        }
    }
}
```

This class will be accessed by my activities like following.

```
public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity{ 
    String returnedData;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        MyLibrary myLibraryObject = new MyLibrary();
        returnedData = myLibraryObject.getMyData("cih");

        /* do something with returnedData */
    }      

}
```

Any suggestions would be a huge help to me. As I am a novice, this might be a stupid question, but my concept is to *reuse codes*.

Comment: "but my concept is to reuse codes." then use retrofit or volley

Comment: Yes you can, you just have to call this class from the activity. And you should use callbacks to return the result via another method in onPostExecute() to your main activity @AdityaAmit.

Comment: @GeorgePJ Actually I wanted to achieve this without using a framework.

Comment: Hi @Raj, I tried returning value from onPostExecute() method, didn't work. Also I tried putting up get/set methods inside the AsyncTask class and accessing them from the outer class, it returned null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your planning to do this asynchronous manner then you should use a interface as callback or u can get result by calling get method in AsyncTask

```
protected String getMyData(String param){
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("param1", apicall);
        params.put("param2", param);
        MyAsyncClass myAsyncClass = new MyAsyncClass(params);
       myData= myAsyncClass.execute().get();

        /* Here after finishing the task I want to return the data to the caller */
        return myData;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! execute().get() returns the 'result' produced by doInBackground(). I can parse the result inside getMyData() and return to caller activity.

Comment: Grt. issue with this approch is it will wait for network call complete, if need asynchronous nature you need to implement callback functionality using interface.

Answer (score 0):

I think refrofit might solve your problem. You can search for `retrofit interceptor`